# Interpretation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of combinatorial Hodge Laplacian in algebraic topology

Tags: algebraic-topology, hodge-theory, betti-numbers

Let $\Sigma$ be an abstract simplicial complex. Do the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the combinatorial Hodge Laplacian $\Delta_k$,

$$\Delta_k^\Sigma = (\partial_k^\Sigma)^\dagger \partial_k^\Sigma + \partial_{k+1}^\Sigma (\partial_{k+1}^\Sigma)^\dagger$$

have an interpretation in the field of algebraic topology? For example, the chains $f$ that are solutions to the Laplace equation $\Delta f = 0$ can be interpreted as the representative of the homology class and the shortest cycle around a certain $k$-hole. Can the other eigenchains, whose eigenvalue is $>0$, be interpreted in some way? Is an eigenchain with a corresponding eigenvalue slightly bigger than zero different from an instance with a large eigenvalue associated?

It seems to me that cohomology theory allows for an interesting interpretation, where $f \in \mathcal{C}^k$ cochain are eigenvectors of the combinatorial Laplacian, $\Delta f = \lambda f$, and $\lambda$ is interpreted as the frequency of the function (e.g., [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0165168421001870)). Can we derive an interpretation in algebraic topology from this theory?

A possible input [here](https://cyphynets.lums.edu.pk/images/HOL-MTNS2006.pdf):

> 2. Near-harmonic forms and quantitative topology: The operation of the
>    Laplacian on a co-chain indicates how close it is to being a
>    cohomology class. This lets one to quantify the fragilities of a
>    simplicial complex. The eigenvectors corresponding to small non-zero
>    eigenvalues indicate what parts of the complex are close to becoming
>    holes. This is a more useful abstraction of network holes than merely
>    knowing their absence or presence. Work needs to be done in order to
>    quantify these notions more carefully